# QGSI shortes path method using existing nodes, selecting them by name

Tags: qgis

QGIS Setup:

Layer 1) nodes
Layer 2) line layer connecting the nodes (network)

Problem:
I want to use the shortest path method lets say from node "A" to node "Z", selecting them by their names. I only found the option to click on the map extracting the coordinates.
Is there a method to use the names of the nodes as start/ Endpoints?

Comment: You could extract nodes A and Z to a new layer, then use `Shortest path (layer to point)` (or `point to layer`).

Comment: thank u :) it works. But I also want to know the nodes passing on the shortest path from A to Z. Is there another way?

Comment: Extract vertices, intersect with the shortest path output.